# How does parent's z-index affect the child's z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>
   qqq
  </p>
  <div id="child" >
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

If I don't set the parent's z-index to 1, the child's z-index will let it under the parent. But when I set the parent's z-index to 1 (or any number higher than 0), the child's z-index won't work!

Why is this happening?

Comment: How would it not work? It goes behind the parent?

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Giving the parent a z-index value starts a new stacking order. Once you give the parent a z-index value then all the z-index values for its children will be relative to the parent's z-index value.

Comment: I want the child under the parent so I set child z-index to 0. That work! But when I set the parent's z-index to 1, previous stage will not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "under"? Under like underneath or under like behind? If it is behind it can not be visible. That is what `z-index` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all background colour goes behind the text. the `z-index` default is auto which states "Sets the stack order equal to its parents". However, using `z-index` on the child will move it out of the natural stack order and place it behind the background. If you change the parent to also have a Z-Index then it will rejoin the stack and the background colour will again appear behind the text.

Both parent and child are set to AUTO. Both in the same stack.

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
   qqq
  </div>
  <div id="child" >
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Child set to `z-index -1` now it is not in the same stack as the parent

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
   qqq
  </div>
  <div id="child" >
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Child set to `z-index -1` and parent set to `z-index 1` making them both in the same stack so the background color gets put behind both elements.

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
   qqq
  </div>
  <div id="child" >
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't fully get this.  So, in OP's question, if you add a `background: blue;` to `#child` ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fbzkdvr/)), then the blue background also beats the red background, even though it has lower z-index.  It seems the child beats the parent in everything.